# navigation bar back button , crash the app

Tags: ios

I have navigation based application. I have created a `UINavigationController` in application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` delegate method like this:

```
self.initialviewcontroller = [[InitialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InitialViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *myNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.initialviewcontroller];

self.window.rootViewController = myNavController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In the `InitialViewController` I have a button which will navigate to `SecondViewController`. So, in the button's action I push the `SecondViewController` as follow:

```
if(self.secondView != nil)
  self.secondView = nil;
self.secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondView animated:YES];
```

Situation : The navigation is working fine, I am able to navigate between `InitialViewController` to `SecondViewController`. When I am in `SecondViewController` and press home button of device, the application is entered into background and when i reopen the app it opens the app from where I close it (i.e SecondViewController). Now if i press the back button to go to InitialViewController, the app is crashing.

It's working fine in the ios simulator, but crashes occurs on devices.

I didn't understand what the mistake I have done?

here is my error code

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x654b495d
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Comment: Send us the text of the error.

Comment: Also, when your nib is the same name as your View Controller you can just use `[[SecondViewController alloc] init];` and it'll default to the nib of the same name.

Comment: I think the problem is that when the app enter in background the system is releasing the `InitialViewController` instance, to be sure you can add `NSLog()` calls in the `dealloc` method of `InitialViewController` class

Comment: `UINavigationController` does retain each of its child `UIViewcontroller` objects. But it's certainly worth checking with NSLogs in each of the initialViewController state-change methods, like `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: UINavigationController is retained in it's child UIViewcontroller objects, i am able to push another view controller from there....

Comment: Also i have checked the self.navigationController.viewControllers count also it's showing the correct count ...

Comment: I have the problem when app is reopens from the background mode to active, it will show the view controller where the app is entered into background, but it crash when press back button to go to the previous view......

Comment: And also it's working fine in the simulator 4.3..... with no crashes..

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is

```
if(self.secondView != nil)
  self.secondView = nil;
self.secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondView animated:YES];
```

instead of this Use the following.

```
SecondViewController *secondViewobj = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewobj animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the uinavigationcontroller is getting deallocated.
You should put your secondView in a uinavigationcontroller like the first one and try again.

Hope this helps :)